# C# How to cast object to ICollection of objects

Tags: c#, collections, casting, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a variable which I get from reflections using this syntax (`property` is a string):

```
            T entity = DbContext.Set<T>()
               .Include(property)
               .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == key);
            var navPropertyCollection = Properties
               .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == property)
              ?.GetValue(entity);
```

`navPropertyCollection` is an object, but in a class it's declared as `ICollection<MyClass>` and initialized as `List<MyClass>`. This is working:

```
            var navPropertyCollection = Properties
               .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == property)
              ?.GetValue(entity) as List<MyClass>;
```

But I don't know MyClass (and don't need to is this method at all)! I only know it's child of MyBaseClass.
I need to cast it into something like `ICollection<dynamic>`, `ICollection<object>`, `ICollection<MyBaseClass>`, `List<dynamic>`, `List<object>` or `List<MyBaseClass>`. But these casts doesn't work.
Casting to `IEnumerable<object>` or `IEnumerable<MyBaseClass>` works, but this is not the option because later I need to call method `Add()`, and changes are not marked in my `DbContext`.

Comment: Are you sure that casting to the non-generic `IList` doesn't work? I'd expect that to work, and would allow you to call `Add` later.

Comment: @JonSkeet I forgot about non-generic IList. Please make an answer. And thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're certain that the value of the property will be a `List<T>` or some other generic collection that implements the non-generic `IList` interface, I'd suggest casting to that. (I would cast rather than using `as` though, to avoid masking unexpected types.)

So:

```cs
var navPropertyCollection = (IList) Properties
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == property)
    ?.GetValue(entity);
```